# Shell script: get the exit status of a failed background child process in Solaris

Tags: shell, solaris

I have written a POC .This code works fine in Linux but not in Solaris. I am using Solaris 10

```
enter code here
#!/bin/sh
echo inside parent
echo executing child in the background
./remove deepti & # executing dummy command to make sure that background process fails
childpid=$!
i=0
while [ `ps -p $childpid >/dev/null; echo $?` = 0 ]; do
    sleep 5
    i=`expr $i + 1`
    if [ $i -gt 3 ]; then
        echo wait exceeded
        ps -p $childpid >/dev/null
        exit $?
    fi
done
wait $childpid
exit $?
```

I expect that Wait shall return me the exit status of background command . exit status should be 127 . However I get exit status as 0.

Comment: Format the code properly can't read it.

Comment: if I ebnter the code snippet here then by default entire code is coming in a paragraph. How to avoid this?

Comment: @userXXX: Please indent code with four spaces so that StackOverflow recognizes it as code to be formatted. I've do it for you, please read the [formatting help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for details on how two write questions that people want to answer :-)

Comment: What is "remove deepti" doing ? Please provide a reproducible case. Also, you can edit out "enter code here" from your code sample.

Comment: You should be able to change `while [ `ps -p $childpid >/dev/null; echo $?` = 0 ]` to `while ps -p $childpid >/dev/null` (no brackets, backticks, `echo`).

Comment: or even, `while kill -0 $childpid`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a bug but the expected and documented behavior of /bin/sh on Solaris. Quoted from [wait(1) manual page](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19253-01/816-5165/wait-1/index.html):

***If pid is not an active process ID, the wait utility will return immediately and the return code will be 0.***

Older Bourne shell documentation was not specifying what wait should do when invoked with already dead processes so the result was undefined behavior. The documentation was fixed to clarify that point in 1998. ksh was the recommended way to get the expected return status: http://bugs.opensolaris.org/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4068875

With Solaris 10 and older, /bin/sh is a legacy scripting language that shouldn't be used with new code. You'd rather use /bin/ksh or /usr/xpg4/bin/sh instead for POSIX scripts. Solaris 11 Express provides a POSIX /bin/sh so this kind of issues would no more happen.

Comment: Thanks a lot Problem was indeed with /bin/sh. If I use /bin/bash or /bin/ksh the code works perferctly. To make it work on sh, I need to go to /usr/xpg4/bin/sh and change the first line in script to /usr/xpg4/bin/sh

Comment: @Deepti, what the heck, that's what I told you to do!

Comment: Seems you're 100% right! (On both POSIX and this), I be the first to admit when I'm wrong.

Comment: Thanks. Why not voting up my reply then ? By the way, because you removed your answer, your "what the heck" comment is now lacking context.